# Sum of two columns from two tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

```
t1
CustId    Name
1         XYZ
2         PQR

t2
CustId    Income
1         100
1         200
2         50
2         100

t3
CustId   Expense
1        50
1        70
2        30
2        40
```

I need to run a query where I get the below result

```
CustId    Total Income     Total Expense
1         300              120
2         150              70
```

I have tried the normal SUM and Group By but the result is very different from the expected...

The Query I attempted was

```
SELECT t1.custid, SUM(t2.Income), SUM(t3.Expense) FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.custId = t2.CustId
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.CustId = t3.CustId
GROUP BY t1.CustId
```

Any help you would appreciated....

Comment: Can you paste the query you attempted and its result?

Comment: The query you pasted seems ok to me. What's wrong with the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query.

```
SELECT t1.CustID, IFNULL(tbl1.Income,0) AS 'TotalIncome', IFNULL(tbl2.Expenses,0) AS 'TotalExpenses' 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.CustID,SUM(Income) AS 'Income' FROM t2 GROUP BY t2.CustID) tbl1
ON t1.CustID = tbl1.CustID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t3.CustID,SUM(Expenses) AS 'Expenses' FROM t3 GROUP BY t3.CustID) tbl2
ON t1.CustID = tbl2.CustID;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad05d/8

Comment: That did the trick... Thanks @RBB08 But why didn't my way worked? It works perfectly for single tables...

Comment: Because the number of rows was being multiplied by the second join. Suppose you had two incomes and three expenses. The incomes were being triplicated and the expenses were being duplicated.

Comment: @shawnt00 is correct. Because the first join created a temporary table before JOINING to your third table because of this the first JOIN already have two rows returned per CustID and when JOIN to your third table it will now give you 4 rows per CustID with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing inner join all three tables and then grouping the result by customer id like:

```
SELECT t1.custId, SUM(t2.Income), SUM(t3.expense)
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.custId = t2.custId
INNER JOIN t3
ON t2.custId = t3.custId
GROUP BY t1.custId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to achieve what you want

`SELECT t1.custid, ti.Income, te.expense FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (select t2.custId, sum(t2.Income) as income from t2 group by t2.custId) as ti ON t1.custId = ti.CustId LEFT JOIN (select t3.custId, sum(t3.Expense) as expense from t3 group by t3.custId) as te ON t1.CustId = te.CustId`

As far as why your previous query did not worked. I can give the following explanation.

In SQL when ever you do a join, the way database internally makes a cartesian product of all the entries and depending on the where clause the data is returned. So when you did

```
SELECT t1.custid, SUM(t2.Income), SUM(t3.Expense) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.custId = t2.CustId
```

You got 4 rows, where customerId is repeated in the rows, now when you join with t3 table by applying the equal condition on customerId, database would be able to match customerID in two records and hence you get 8 rows. That is why your query was not working